# How to include paths to PHAR archives in the open-basedir directive?

Tags: php, composer-php, phar, open-basedir

I'm trying to use [composer](http://www.getcomposer.org) on my local development machine, and it always fails when trying to copy something from the PHAR archive:

```
[ErrorException]
copy(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(phar://E:/xampp/php/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) is not within the allowed path(s)
```

**E:\xampp\php\composer** is included in the **open_basedir** directive, reading and writing files in that location works fine, only accessing files in the PHAR archive doesn't work. I've tried adding the following paths:

```
E:\xampp\php\composer\composer.phar\src\
phar://E:/xampp/php/composer/
phar://E:/xampp/php/composer/composer.phar/src/
phar://E:/xampp/php/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/
```

but none of it helps, it's still failing with the same error.

Is there a special way to include paths to PHAR archives? Is it possible at all? Should it be neccessary anway? Might this have something to do with this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64634 ?

My system: Windows 7 x64, XAMPP 1.8.1, Apache 2.4.3, PHP 5.4.7

**Update:** Tried the latest stable PHP 5.4.14 too, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce it and the workaround using stream_copy_to_stream seems to work, so I applied that in [566313834af3a49cd3f6b41001f7d8549e0b9c96](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/566313834af3a49cd3f6b41001f7d8549e0b9c96) and if you run composer self-update it should now work.

I am not too sure which other parts of composer might be affected by this, but if you still have similar issues feel free to open a bug report on github.

Comment: Thanks for the ultra fast fix/workaround, it's working fine now :) So since **stream_copy_to_stream** works in this case too I guess that also answers the question, ie it's actually the mentioned PHP bug causing the problem.